# How can I retrieve a specific field from a map in Cloud Firestore using Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is a part of data saved in firebase Firestore:

[image]

How can I get (`fName`) from (`newFriend0`) in Java?

This is part of the code. It gave the entire map. I want just a specific field such as ("jem" for (fName))

```
Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){

if (entry.getKey().equals("Friends")){

f=document.getString("FName");////not worked

Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());
                                                   }
                                               }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried so far that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Please add what Doug asked for and please also respond with @

Comment: @AlexMamo .. Thanks in advance Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** July, 16th 2201

As a matter of fact, there is a simpler way of getting that data:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

---

Seeing that your code is in Java, please see the solution below:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("coll").document("9999").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> friendsMap = document.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : friendsMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().equals("Friends")) {
                        Map<String, Object> newFriend0Map = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : newFriend0Map.entrySet()) {
                            if (e.getKey().equals("newFriend0")) {
                                Map<String, Object> fNameMap = (Map<String, Object>) e.getValue();
                                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> dataEntry : fNameMap.entrySet()) {
                                    if (dataEntry.getKey().equals("fName")) {
                                        Log.d("TAG", dataEntry.getValue().toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
jem
```

Didn't see the name of your collection in the screenshot, so I named it simply `coll` but you should definitely change it to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to perform 2 steps, [retrieve the document data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) with one of the provided libraries and then manipulate the resulting map object with the means of your programming language.

Here is a simple Nodejs example getting 'fName':

```
let docRef = db.collection('<collection_name>').doc('9999');
docRef.get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', doc.data().Friends.newFriend0.fName);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
  });
```

Comment: `DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("coll").document("9999");
// asynchronously retrieve the document
ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
// ...
// future.get() blocks on response
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
if (document.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Document data: " + document.getData());
} else {
  System.out.println("No such document!");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Firestore document is in JSON format thus we can just convert the `documentSnapshot.getData()` to String first then to JSON so it will be more easier to access the Map objects data without needing too many loops/iteration. Another way is to do it like this `documentSnapshot.getData().get("get_only_map_key_to_be_converted_as_JSON")` convert it to string then to JSON as well. The possible remaining problem is if you store url in your document's map object which will have a problem as those link needs to be unescaped to become a valid JSON though I haven't tried that scenario yet in Android Java.